# pytorch simulate dropout when evaluating model against test data

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

We are training a resnet model using the CIFAR 10 dataset and we are trying to do the following:

After we have trained the model itself we want to simulate dropout during the model evaluation when we are feeding the test data to it.
I know it might sound weird because dropout is a regularization mechanism, but we are doing it as part of an experiment

One option that we are considering to try to to use the `state_dict`, create a deep copy to have the original values, and then modify values it in manually.

We also saw that `net.eval()` is changing the dropout layer into eval mode instead of training mode, maybe there is a way to utilize this mechanism to simulate dropout during evaluation ?

I want to ask if there are better ways to achieve what I am trying to do ?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question correctly. Why just don't call `model.eval`? keep the model in train mode, and call it with `torch.no_grad` context

Comment: I want to still keep the dropout behavior during the evaluation of the model against the test data. Is the solution that you are suggesting doing it?

Comment: Leaving the model in training mode (i.e. not calling `model.eval()`) will keep dropout enabled. The only concern would be if the model also uses batch normalization which would be impacted by not putting the model into eval mode. You could also just call `.train()` on each of the dropout layers after putting the model in eval to reenable them. That could be done manually or with `model.apply`.

Comment: @jodag thank you for pointing out, you are right, I missed that.

Comment: @jodag our model is something that we built manually so we can easily create all the Resnet variants, do you think that it would be easier to do what you are saying ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dropout module is disabled during evaluation mode, i.e. after `nn.Module.eval` is called on your model. If you want it to be enabled after calling `.eval` then you can call `nn.Module.train` on each of the `nn.Dropout` modules within your model. The `nn.Module.apply` method makes this pretty easy. You can encapsulate this all in an override of your model's `train` method.

```py
class MyModel(nn.Module):
    ... # your model's implementation
        
    # note that self.eval() just calls self.train(False) which is why
    # we are overriding train
    def train(self, mode=True):
        # recursively applies train mode to self and submodules
        super().train(mode)

        # When mode=false (i.e. .eval() is called), re-enable dropout layers
        # by recursively applying this function to each submodule
        def enable_dropout(mod: nn.Module):
            if isinstance(mod, nn.Dropout):
                mod.train()

        if not mode:
            self.apply(enable_dropout)

        return self


model = MyModel ...
```

that way after calling `model.eval()`, everything except dropout layers will behave as if they are in evaluation mode. Calling `model.train()` will work as it did before.

Of course if you don't want to override the model you could do this outside of the model.

```py
# if you don't want to override the train method then you can just do the
# same thing as the above snippet outside of the class method. E.g.

model.eval()

def enable_dropout(mod: nn.Module):
    if isinstance(mod, nn.Dropout):
        mod.train()

model.apply(enable_dropout)
```